# Understanding sys.dm_exec_query_stats execution_count vs creation_time

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, performance, dmv, performance-tuning

I've just downloaded the SQL Server 2012 ['Performance Dashboard Reports'](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29063) and am having some issues interpreting the data shown by one of the results and linking it back to the DMV `sys.dm_exec_query_stats`.

According to the CPU report, my worst performing query is an insert statement that has run ~27K times.

When I take the `query_hash` for the query and put it into the query below, I get 62 results, each with the same `query_hash` and `query_plan_hash` but with different `plan_handle` values.

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) AS dest
WHERE query_hash = 0x1561B563078359C1
```

According to [BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189741.aspx), the `execution_count` shows:

> Number of times that the plan has been executed since it was last compiled.

and `creation_time` shows

> Time at which the plan was compiled.

I am 99.9% sure the query runs once every 5 minutes, yet each query in the result set has a plan `creation_time` of this morning and yet `execution_count` shows ~400 for each one.

How does SQL Server determine this figure? Are the figures somehow linked by `plan_hash` or are they unique for each `plan_handle`?

Answer (score 5):

`sys.dm_exec_query_stats` returns aggregated stats for plans, but with a row per query.

So if a procedure has 2 queries, then `sys.dm_exec_query_stats` would return 2 rows, but the plan-related columns (such as compile time, execution count, etc) are plan level stats, and cannot be further aggregated.